# Polymorphic Type Parameters in Generic Collections

Tags: c#, generics

Why does the C# compiler not allow polymorphic type (T) parameters in generic collections (ie, List[T]) ?

Take class 'A' and 'B' for example, where 'B' is a subclass of 'A'

```
class A { }
class B : A { }
```

and consider a function that takes a list of type 'A'

```
void f(List<A> aL) { }
```

that gets called with a list of type 'B'

```
List<B> bL = new List<B>();

f(bL);
```

The following error is given

```
ERROR: cannot convert from List<B> to List<A>
```

What semantic rule is being violated ?

Also is there an "elegant" mean to this end, aside from looping through and casting each element (I want some sugar please) ?  Thanks.

Comment: "What semantic rule is being violated?" - the Liskov substitution principle.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio, C#?

Comment: @Rake36 Shouldn't matter, what the OP is trying to is simply not typesafe.

Comment: you will find many good answers on covariance. In your case, if you change f to `void f(IEnumerable<A> aL) { }` it will work, as IEnumerable is covariant with A.

Comment: If it has to be a list, you can use extension methods to avoid having to write the loops explicitly: `bL.Cast<A>().ToList()`.

Comment: @millimoose: I was thinking of some of the slight differences in C# versions.  i.e. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245607/how-is-generic-covariance-contra-variance-implemented-in-c-sharp-4-0

Comment: @Rake36 I know there's differences, but in this case the only built-in solution is "use `IEnumerable<T>`" which I believe was always special-cased to be covariant even before the `in` and `out` modifiers came into the language. Hence my "shouldn't matter" - it's possible that in the OP's use case it might but not very likely since they're not doing anything with delegates.

Comment: @millimoose I was wondering about your "shouldn't matter" comment myself... Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In C#, why can't a List<string> object be stored in a List<object> variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557/in-c-why-cant-a-liststring-object-be-stored-in-a-listobject-variable)

Comment: @Euphoric Yeah, but mine is posed for legacy! (lol, jk)

Comment: This question is asked several times a day.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`List<B>` simply is not a subtype of `List<A>`. (I'm never sure about what "covariant" and what "contravariant" is in this context so I'll stick with "subtype".) Consider the case where you do this:

```
void Fun(List<A> aa) {
    aa(new A());
}

var bb = new List<B>();
Fun(bb); // whoopsie
```

If what you want to do was allowed it would be possible to add an `A` to a list of `B`s which is clearly not type-safe.

Now, clearly it's possible to *read* elements from the list safely, which is why C# lets you create [covariant (i.e. "read-only") interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469487.aspx) - which let the compiler know it's not possible to cause this sort of corruption through them. If you only need read access, for collections, the usual one is `IEnumerable<T>`, so in your case you might just make the method:

```
void Fun(IEnumerable<A> aa) { ... }
```

and use the `Enumerable` methods - most should be optimised if the underlying type is `List`.

Unfortunately, because of how the C# generics stuff works, *classes* can't be variant at all, only interfaces. And as far as I know, all the collection interfaces "richer" than `IEnumerable<T>` are "read-write". You could technically make your own covariant wrapper interface that only exposes the read operations you want.

Answer (score 12):

Take this little example as to why this cannot work. Imagine we have another subtype `C` of `A`:

```
class A {}
class B : A {}
class C : A {}
```

Then obviously, I can put a `C` object in a `List<A>` list. But now imagine the following function taking an A-list:

```
public void DoSomething (List<A> list)
{
    list.Add(new C());
}
```

If you pass a `List<A>` it works as expected because `C` is a valid type to put in a `List<A>`, but if you pass a `List<B>`, then you cannot put a `C` into that list.

For the general problem that’s happening here, see [covariance and contravariance for arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29#Arrays).

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing inherently wrong with passing a collection of `B` to a method that expects a collection of `A`. However, there are many things that can go wrong depending on what you are going to do with the collection.

Consider:

```
void f(List<A> aL)
{
    aL.(new A()); // oops! what happens here?
}
```

Obviously there is a problem here: if `aL` were allowed to be a `List<B>` then this implementation would result in some type of runtime error, either on the spot or (much worse) if later on the code handles the `A` instance we put in as a `B`.

The compiler does not allow you to use a `List<B>` as a `List<B>` in order to preserve type safety and guarantee that your code will not need runtime checks to be correct. Note that this behavior is different than what (unfortunately) happens with arrays -- the language designer's decision is a tradeoff, and they decided differently on different occasions:

```
void f(A[] arr)
{
    arr[0] = new A(); // exception thrown at runtime
}

f(new B[1]);
```

Comment: Thank you Sir for your deep insight into this matter.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be looking for 'out' generic modifiers, which allow for covariance between two generic types.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469487.aspx

An example as posted on that page:

```
// Covariant delegate. 
public delegate R DCovariant<out R>();

// Methods that match the delegate signature. 
public static Control SampleControl()
{ return new Control(); }

public static Button SampleButton()
{ return new Button(); }

public void Test()
{            
    // Instantiate the delegates with the methods.
    DCovariant<Control> dControl = SampleControl;
    DCovariant<Button> dButton = SampleButton;

    // You can assign dButton to dControl 
    // because the DCovariant delegate is covariant.
    dControl = dButton;

    // Invoke the delegate.
    dControl(); 
}
```

I'm not sure whether C# currently supports covariance for its current collections.

Comment: Excellent example, this should help a lot when I can get some time to explore this concept of convariance. Thanks Kenogu.

Answer (score 1):

You error is that B inherits from A; but `List<B>` don't inherits from `List<A>`. `List<A> != A`;

You can do this:

```
List<A> aL = new List<A>();
aL.Add(new B());

f (aL)
```

You can detect the type in void `f(List<A> list)`

```
foreach(A a in list)
{
  if (a is B)
    //Do B stuff
  else
    //Do A stuff
}
```

Comment: Ahh, I was suspecting this, but don't like cluttering my questions with my own hypothetical answers, and so didn't mention. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

your question is very similar to [mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17447491/casting-in-templete-inner-value-problems):
the answer is that you can't do that cast because thoose are diferent types create by a template class and they do not inherit. what you can do is:

```
f(bL.Cast<A>());
```

Comment: +1 Your "different types" explaination gives a precise reason why this doesn't work, so thank you, and nice syntax, I'll give it a try.

Comment: @samusArin wow, i've never seen anyone putting so much effort commenting every answe! just for that i'll search every good answer you gave and +1 them. keep up the good work

Comment: Thank you, but you really didn't have to... I do it b/c I appreciate all helpful answers, even though I can only accept one. I think its quiet rude to ignore people that are helping you, let alone at least acknowledge their help and efforts !!