# Create Dynamic <T> in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I need to create Dynamic T using interface. But I am getting "Type Casting" error. 
Here is my code :

```
interface IEditor { }

class Editor : IEditor { }

class Test<T> { }
```

Now the  will be dynamic so I am using this code below :

```
Test<IEditor> lstTest = (Test<IEditor>)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Test<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(Editor)));
```

I am getting following error

> Unable to cast object of type 'CSharp_T.Test`1[CSharp_T.Editor]' to type 'CSharp_T.Test`1[CSharp_T.IEditor]'.

This error is not compilation error but I am getting run time error.

Comment: I dunno if "dynamic" is the best name for your question, because it may be confused with the dynamic keyword, which has nothing to do with this. P.S. This looks wrong typeof(Test<>) You didn't include a type in the brackets?

Comment: Is the interface and class really empty?

Comment: The error message seems incomplete.

Comment: I am not getting compilation error but i am getting run time error

Comment: Also I believe the reason for the error is that a `Test<Editor>` isn't a subtype of `Test<IEditor>`, and thus you can't cast the former to the latter. This has nothing to do with your use of `Activator`, even `(Test<IEditor>) new Test<Editor>()` would fail. The explanation for this can probably be found on Stack Overflow in hundreds of variants.

Comment: @Alan is correct typeof(IEditor) or typeOf(Editor) maybe.

Comment: @Alan `typeof(Test<>)` is perfectly valid, it's a way to get a reference to the generic type without parameters.

Comment: One of my answers about the reason why that relationship between types isn't there, explained with `List`s: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17952546/polymorphic-type-parameters-in-generic-collections/17952762#17952762

Comment: Thanks @millimoose for your inputs. But how can I cast (Test<IEditor>) new Test<Editor>() ? Is there any way ?

Comment: @DebajitMukherjee You can't as they stand. The types are not compatible. It would be in violation of a fundamental principle the type system is based on. You'd need to introduce a new `interface ITest<out TEditor>` and use that, but then you'd have the restriction that `TEditor` can only be used as the return type of a method. (Or maybe an `out` parameter as well, I don't know this by heart.)

Comment: @Alan Seems the correct terms for what I mean on MSDN is *generic type definition* (e.g. `Dictionary<,>`) and *constructed generic type* (e.g. `Dictionary<string, int>`): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172192.aspx

Comment: While `typeof(Test<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(Editor))` is correct and works correctly, in this case, where both `Type` objects are "constants", it is much easier to write simply `typeof(Test<Editor>)`.

Comment: Also, you don't show any of the constructors, so we can't see why you can't just use `new Test<Editor>()` instead of the `Activator` stuff. Are there any cases where the `new` expression will fail while this specific overload of `CreateInstance` works?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generic classes do not support covariance, but interfaces do. If you define an interface `ITest<>` and mark `T` as an `out` parameter, like this,

```
interface IEditor { }

class Editor : IEditor { }

interface ITest<out T> { }

class Test<T> : ITest<T> { }
```

you will be able to do this:

```
ITest<IEditor> lstTest = (ITest<IEditor>)Activator
    .CreateInstance(typeof(Test<>)
    .MakeGenericType(typeof(Editor)));
```

However, this would limit the ways in which the `T` parameter could be used inside `ITest<>` and its implementations.

[Demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/uYyrlo).

Answer (score 1):

`Test` is not covariant (it is invariant in it's generic argument).  Because of this a `Test<IEditor>` is not a subtype of a `Test<IEditor>`.  There is no relationship between those two types.

You can create an object of type `Test<IEditor>` to begin with, instead of a `Test<IEditor>`, and then the cast can succeed.