# Generic collection polymorphism type as parameter

Tags: c#, generics, data-binding, casting

consider the following structure

```
class A {}
class B : A {}
class C : A {}
class D : A {}
...

// in data source class
BindingList<B> d1;
BindingList<C> d2;
BindingList<D> d3;
...

// in datagridview class
void BindDataSource(BindingList<A> source);
void QueryDataSource() {
  BindingList<A> source = (BindingList<A>)dgv.DataSource;
  A a = source.First(...);
}
```

I'd like to bind `d1` and `d2` ... to a `DataGridView` through `BindDataSource` sot that any change to `d1` and `d2` will automatically be reflected in `DataGridView`. From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17952546/polymorphic-type-parameters-in-generic-collections) I learned that the above code is not valid. But none of the solutions in that post apply to my situation. I tried to change `BindDataSource` to the following

```
void BindingDataSource<T>(BindingList<T> source) where T:A;
```

but now `QueryDataSource` does not compile as I cannot cast the DataSource. Is there any way to solve the whole thing ?

Comment: If you're only querying using LINQ, per your example, then why not cast your `DataSource` to `IEnumerable<A>` (your linked question suggests this).  `IEnumerable<T>` is co-variant, all 3 of your lists are `IEnumerable<A>`..

Answer (score 1):

A few options.

Option 1: Let d1...d3 be `BindingList<A>` instances, but only insert B, C,
    D into them.

Option 2: Have one collection, and query out/filter by
    B, C and D when needed.

Option 3: Do something like this.

```
BindDataSource(
    new BindingList<A>(d1.ToList<A>())
)
```

Option 4: Use a generic method.

```
void BindDataSource<T>(BindingList<T> list) where T : A { }
```